# Django Default Auth Views Url No Reverse Match

Tags: django, url, django-authentication

In my Django Project, I have the following in my `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('register/', views.register, name='register'), # Registration

path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'), # Login Page
path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(next_page='misc:index'), name='logout'), # Logout Page

path('change_password/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='users/change_password.html', success_url='/'), name='change_password'), # Password Change Page

# Password reset pages; They take a lot of parameters
path('reset_password/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
    template_name='users/password_reset/password_reset_request.html', 
    email_template_name='users/password_reset/email_password_reset.html', 
    subject_template_name='users/password_reset/email_password_reset_subject.txt',
    success_url='/reset_password/check_your_email/',
    from_email='password-reset@sn.local',
    html_email_template_name='users/password_reset/email_password_reset.html'
    ), name='password_reset_request'),
path('reset_password/check_your_email/', views.password_reset_check_your_email, name='password_reset_check_your_email'),
path('reset_password/<uidb64>/<slug:token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
    template_name='users/password_reset/password_reset_form.html', 
    post_reset_login=True, 
    success_url='/'), name='password_reset_form'),
]
```

All the urls work fine, except the last one which gives me a no reverse match error.

The url I am trying to use is: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/reset_password/bAAAAAA/52s-c48e21c49899996ec19c/`

When I try to visit it, it gives me this error:

`Reverse for 'password_reset_form' with keyword arguments '{'uidb64': '', 'token': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['reset_password/(?P<uidb64>[^/]+)/(?P<token>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']`

Edit:

`users/password_reset/password_reset_form.html`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Reset Password{% endblock title %}

{% block content %} 
<form action="{% url 'users:password_reset_form' uidb64=uidb64 token=token %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Reset Password</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

I feel like I am missing something here...

Any help would be grately appreciated

Comment: You need to show your users/password_reset/password_reset_form.html.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Added!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PasswordResetConfirmView doesn't send the values of `uidb64` or `token` to the template context, which is why they appear blank in that error message.

But you don't need them. The form is just posting back to the same URL that displayed it in the first place. So just do:

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

Comment: when I do this, the page loads, but there is no form. just a submit button

Comment: Apparently form Is Set To None

Comment: The form is None if "validlink" is False, ie if the token/uidb64 combination have already been used.